# Visualization of the Garbage Collector

Tags: java, object, null, garbage-collection, profiler

In the code below, there will be one object `s2` that is eligible for garbage collection. Is there any way to visualize the work of Garbage Collector in Netbeans 8.0? Profile/Debug/Watch/Plugin?

```
class Student {
       String name;
       int age;
    }

public class Test_Garbage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Student s1 = new Student();
     Student s2 = new Student();
     Student s3 = new Student();
        s1 = s3;
        s3 = s2;
        s2 = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should note that the garbage collector only does work when it needs to (or as late as possible) and in this case, it doesn't need to so there is nothing to see.

Comment: Thanks, but its any way to find when a visualize it?

Comment: The only tool which shows you what it is doing as it happens is `jstat`  This will allow you to see objects being copied from Eden to Survivor and to tenured.  However, it needs to be on the large scale. i.e. you cannot only see GCs taking multiple seconds i.e. many millions of objects.  In general, you only need to worry about these details on the very large scale.

Answer (score 1):

i am using  Visual GC Plugin in JVisualVM that gives good visualization of objects across generations(Young/Survivir/Tenured). See [here](https://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html) how to install it

That's the best tool i have found as of now that too comes with jdk

Comment: Flight Recorder is also an excellent tool which comes with JDK 8.

Comment: Good to know that. Thanks. Will explore that .

Comment: Flight Recorder is lower overhead for profiling CPU and memory and can sample between safe points for more accurate results. http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/03/java-flight-recorder-since-jdk-18040.html